# aidl is missing android studio

Tags: android, compilation, aidl

```
Environment:
Mac OS 10.10.3
Android studio:1.2.11
grandle:2.2.1
```

the log：

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:generateDebugSources, :generateDebugTestSources]
:preBuild
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:prepareDebugDependencies
:compileDebugAidl FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugAidl'.
> aidl is missing
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
String SDK_DIR = System.getenv("ANDROID_HOME")
if(SDK_DIR == null) {
    Properties props = new Properties()
    props.load(new FileInputStream(project.rootProject.file("local.properties")))
    SDK_DIR = props.get('sdk.dir');
}


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')

    provided files("${SDK_DIR}/platforms/android-17/data/layoutlib.jar")
    //compile files('libs/pass-v1.1.3.jar')
   // compile files('libs/sdk-v1.0.0.jar')
}
```

before this, I had compile the android resource 4.4 on my Mac, and modified some files in OS system, I think it is the reason is that, but I've forget which file, Someone encountered this problem yet

Comment: possible duplicate of [Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl': aidl is missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[image: I solve my issue, set the build tools version from 21.1.2 to 22.0.1, hope it can help who meet the same.]

I solve my issue, set the build tools version from 21.1.2 to 22.0.1, hope it can help who meet the same.

Answer (score 70):

In my case I downloaded version 22 of Android M and Android 5.1.1 using Android Studio 1.2.1.1 but when I try to do a Hello World this same error showed me

So the solution was go to do right click in app like the image below and choose "Open Module Settings".....

[image]

then there you have 2 options. I've changed both with the last version I had.

Compile SDK version to API 21 Lollipop

[image]

and Build Tools Version to 21.1.2

[image]

Finally clean the project and Build

UPDATE
Here is my **build.gradle** to compare with your **build.gradle**.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.bmi"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

**UPDATED**

TO Get Android Studio 1.3 follow this steps

1. Open the Settings window by choosing File > Settings.
2. Choose the Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Updates panel.
3. On the Updates panel, choose the option Automatically check updates for: Canary Chanel.
4. On the Updates panel, select Check Now to check for the latest canary build. 5. Download and install the build when you are prompted.

Then you'll have something like this to update your Android Studio to 1.3 and with this you can test Android M

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jorge. Solved my problem on a Windows 8.1

Comment: This fixed my issue on OSX 10

Comment: Build Tools and Compile SDK V22 will work, too. It's just 23 that's broken.

Comment: Thanks dude! I started a new project this morning (after downloading the Android M preview sdk) and hit that same "aidl missing" error. Your fix worked for me.

Answer (score 15):

For those you are still getting the "aidl is missing" error:

To me, setting back the build tools version is not a solution at all.

On your top level build.gradle file, try setting:
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'`
`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.1'`

and then use `buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'`.

It worked perfectly for me. I hope it helps others.

Comment: This solution is helped me a lot.

Answer (score 8):

Following the screen shots from Jorge's post all you have to do is make sure you **do not** select Build Tools Version 23.0.0 rc1.  I have not fully investigated that version in the IDE or on Google's bug tracker but all I had to do was pick the previous tool version and it worked just fine after doing a clean build.  I tried this out with various SDK min versions.

I am running OSX 10.10.3 with Android Studio 1.2.1.1 running on Oracle JDK 1.8.0_45-b14

***UPDATED WITH SOLUTION***
This issue is identical in nature to [Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl': aidl is missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing/30531882#30531882).  Please read my post for the proper solution and references to the genesis of the solution.

Comment: So I searched Google Android bug tracker and someone had an open issue that I commented on.  An Android Project Member commented that the IDE notifies you to get Gradle Plugin 1.3.0-beta1 if you want to work with Build Tools Version 23.0.0 rc1.  See: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175080

Answer (score 2):

people who are building apps with android studio 1.3 preview might get Debug AIDL missing error
Solution:(Follow in sequence)
1) Download all the tools under preview channel (i.e. revision no 23.0.0 rc1)
2) Download play servies and android support repo support under extras
3)Restart Android Studio
4)Press F4 and set compile SDK version to API 22+ and Build tool version 23.0.0 rc1
5)open build.gradle(Project:******) and change classpath line with classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+'

Comment: Done but still cannot compile 23.0.0 rc1

Answer (score 1):

I followed screenshots from Jorge's post. But did not have API 21 as an option. So I kept Compiled SDK Version 'API 22: Android 5.1 (Lollipop)' as it is and changed Build Tool Version from 23.0.0 rc1 to 22.0.1

I also had to install JDK 7 since 22.0.1 did not support JDK 6. After that gradle build succeded.

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, there is not about *Compile Sdk Version* or *Build Tool Version*, is about the *New Project Structure*. According to this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56160), **Aidl files are supposed to be in src/main/aidl**, once you put *.aidl at the supposed directory, Android Studio would serve it as expect.

And **If you want to have them in src/main/java, then you need the remapping instruction as you've specified**, like below :

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
}
```

btw, in my situation, the remapping approach work only by Gradle 2.4(also probably above version).