# Fresh Install of Android Studio Gradle Error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aidl

Get the following Error when running android studio for the first time.
This is a blank project with no code whatsoever, so I suspect its something I need to configure or install. Any ideas or help? Thanks!

Gradle Build Error:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.

> aidl is missing

Comment: Did you try to Clean and Rebuild the project?

Comment: In my case I had the same problem because I try to see the new version of Android M but I couldn't. My solution to continue working was this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30520628/2091181