# Always "aidl" is missing on Android Studio 1.2.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Android Studio version 1.2.1.1,and every time when create a new app ,error log shows "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.

> aidl is missing" ,I know the solution for this problem is ,to write click on the app directory and select open module settings ,and compiled sdk version and build tool version must set accordingly.I need a proper solution for this problem and i don't want to repeat all these steps on every app creation.Can anybody help me out plz???

Answer (score 6):

You have an invalid combination of project settings in your Gradle build files, probably caused by your installing the M Developer Preview bits from the SDK Manager.

Unless you are specifically trying to test the M Developer Preview, change your `buildToolsVersion` to be `22.0.1` in your app module's `build.gradle` file. Right now, it is probably something like `23.0.0_rc1`.

Comment: Hai ,can you explain why this error occurs again and again at every new app creation.Any proper solution for this problem???.

Comment: @jibinz: "can you explain why this error occurs again and again at every new app creation" -- because you still have the M Developer Preview bits installed. Perhaps Android Studio 1.3 helps here, but that's still in the Canary channel, so I have not touched it. "Any proper solution for this problem?" -- since I have no idea what you would consider a "proper solution" to be, I cannot help you.

Answer (score 3):

May be you are using the Build Tools `23.0.0_rc1`. In this case you have to use the gradle plugin 1.3.0-beta1.

```
buildscript {
     ...
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1'
         ...
     }
}
```

If you are using the build tools `22.0.1`, you can use the gradle plugin `1.1.x or 1.2.x`

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same problem.

Select the app folder and press F4. It'll open the Modular Settings.

(Right-clicking and selecting 'Open Modular Settings' will also do.)

Change 'Build tool version to "22.0.1" from "23.0.0 rc1".

Now this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading "Build tool version" is a workaround, not a solution.

Please check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32495797/4160928