# Aidl is missing error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I want to try out android m preview in my app. I have downloaded the latest build tools and the m platform. I have included this in my build.gradle file (of module app) :

```
compileSdkVersion 'android-MNC'
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc2'
```

In the project build.gradle file, I have included this in my dependencies :

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1"
classpath "com.android.databinding:dataBinder:1.0-rc0"
```

I am using Android Studio 1.3 and SDK tools v24.3.1. This is the output when I try to sync my project.

```
Execution failed for task':app:compileDebugAidl'.
>aidl is missing
```

I have tried the answers given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623448/always-aidl-is-missing-on-android-studio-1-2-1-1) and they are either not applicable or didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this earlier this week.

Change:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta1"
```

to:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0-beta2"
```

to line up with the `rc2` build tools.

Comment: In case someone else also runs into this, in my case I had 1.3-beta2 and got the missing aidl error. Apparently the ".0" is significant.