# AndroidStudio: Failed to sync Install build tools

Tags: android, android-layout, build

Going crazy with this error from about a couple of hours.

The error is:

```
failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc1
```

But I think to have all update (also the release candidate!)

This is the image: thank you.[image]

Comment: you should build your project with tools 22 or less .... take a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506406/aidl-is-missing-android-studio

Comment: Changed the error... Gradle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()' after following other link...

Comment: now see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27735646/android-studio-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-android-error17-0

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clean Blank Android App fails to build - 'failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc1'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859449/clean-blank-android-app-fails-to-build-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-23)

Comment: For who has signed this as duplicated, this question is 05/06/2015 and other one of 16/06/2015. Thank you for your attention ;-)

Comment: Solved here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859449/clean-blank-android-app-fails-to-build-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-23

Answer (score 74):

Go to File > Project Structure > Select Module > Properties you will landing to this screen[image]

Select Build Tools Version same as version selected in Compile Sdk Version.

Hope this will resolve your issue.

Comment: I chose android 6.0 and build tools version 23.0.0 . I got : Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Answer (score 15):

I could fix it by changing it to

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
}
```

in build.gradle file

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue, with Build Tools revision 24.0.0-rc4. **The fix was to install the package using the command line**.

```
~/Android/Sdk| ls -1 build-tools/
23.0.3
24.0.0-rc4
~/Android/Sdk| ./tools/android list sdk -a | grep "SDK Build-tools"
   4- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 24 rc4
   5- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.3
   6- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.2
   7- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
   8- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23 (Obsolete)
   ...
~/Android/Sdk| ./tools/android update sdk -a -u -t 4
   ...
~/Android/Sdk| ls -1 build-tools/
23.0.3
24.0.0-preview
24.0.0-rc4
```

(note that `4` in the `android update sdk` command above refers to the preceding list's number for the desired version, found at the beginning of the line).

The directory `build-tools/24.0.0-rc4/` had been created when I installed the package from Android Studio's SDK Manager. The above method created `build-tools/24.0.0-preview/`.

My app-level `build.gradle` script uses the `-rc4` version, as specified in the setup guide:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-N'
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.0-rc4'
}
```

I do not understand the correlation between `-rc4` and `-preview` or why specifying `24.0.0-rc4` picks up the `-preview` package, but it did fix the issue for me.

Comment: I just run into this problem yesterday. Your solution fixed it and Gradle was able to sync. Now I have this weird error: "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:jillVanillaDebugPackagedLibraries'.
> java.lang.AssertionError: A comparison has not been followed by an if" Do you have any insight?

Comment: Life saver!!! My jenkins was down for this project that I upgraded to N for an hour .

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem.
i have solved this issue by the following point.

First one is go to inside *build.gradle* app file and change this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"
}
```

with this one

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
}
```

I hope this will solve your issue.

Comment: if that worked for you then mark it correct so that it can help other also.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and fixed it by going to File->Project Structure->Project and changing the Android Plugin Version to 1.3.0-beta1

Hope this helps!

Comment: This was the good answers for me too. I create a new project into Android Studio, go to File > Project Structure > Project to copy the version of the Android Plugin and I copy it to my other project. And the sync problem disappear. Thanks a lot to pointing this out !!

Comment: This is the answer which worked for me. Of course, a year later the exact version number differs, but the basic idea of the solution is to update the Android plugin version.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue today,

And solved it easily by following points

1) Start the StandAlone SDK manager (To open the standalone sdk manager - Tools>Android>SDKManager> at Bottom YOu will see a link to launch StandAlone SDK manager)

2) Delete tha package of SDK Build Tools that you have already installed for e.g 24.0.0 rc4.

3) Close the standalone SDK manager then Restart Android Studio.

4) Once after restart the gradle will start building the project and you will get an alert download the package of SDK build tool and Sync. CLick on that and you will start downloading like that...

I hope this helps

Comment: This actually worked for me. Launching "SDK Manager" from the start menu or `android` from `cmd` didn't work at all, but when I used the "StandAlone SDK Manager" it worked -- very weird.

Answer (score 1):

based on your screenshot I can see you have BuildTools ver 23.0.0 rc2 installed. So to get it right open up your gradle build file "build.gradle(Module:app)" and edit buildToolsVersion part like that:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my cases this happened because I changed the time on my computer to load .apk on google play. I spent a few hours to fix "this" problem until I remembered and changed the time back.

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers ask you to use `buildToolsVersion 23.0.0`, but you would get `buildToolsVersion 23.0.0` has serious bugs use `buildToolsVersion 23.0.3`. I did that then I started getting message `buildToolsVersion 23.0.3` is too low from project app update to `buildToolsVersion 25.0.0` and sync again. So I did that and it worked , So here are the final changes.

Inside app's build.gradle change this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc2"
}
```

with this one

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have multiple SDKs locations (might happen if you play around with multiple Android Studio versions and create new location for SDK, what I did), **make sure to check the *local.properties* file** (both of the project and of your module, if you have such structure) and check if the line *sdk.dir=/home/yourSdkLocation* points indeed to the SDK you want to use.

This was the reason it wasn't working for me and it has fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some file access permission/restriction problems. First check to access the below directory manually, check whether your TARGET_VERSION exists, Then check the android sdk manager.

- sdk/build-tools/{TARGET_VERSION}

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I my case the build.gradel(app) was missing  `buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"`. So I open a previously working project to determine the version and added this line `buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"`. Now it works fine.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem with gradle. Now I have solved by installing the highlighted in red. To navigate on this page Open Android studio > Tool > Android > SDK Manager > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools (from tab options) > Show Package details(check box on the right bottom corner). After installing these just refresh the gradle everything will be resolved.[image: sdk download screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

**In case you have error regarding 'SDK build-tools failed' while installing Android Studio, Then you can Download build-tools from** - https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Buildtools

Comment: It's better to answer the question directly here, rather than link out to an article. From the SO guidelines: "Don't include links except to support what you've written. Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer itself."

Comment: Op isn't trying to install Android Studio, please adjust your question to match op's problem

Answer (score -1):

Go to File > Project Structure > Select Module > Properties

After that CLICK on your project which will shown in LEFT PANEL

Then Select Properties
Change Build Tool Version to 22.0.1

It works for sure

Answer (score -1):

**problem:**

> Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc2

**solution:**

```
File > Project Structure > click on Modules > Properties
Change Build Tool Version to 23.0.1
```

its work for me

Answer (score -1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rx5a3.png)

Start the project structure( `file>structure`) 
You can see:
on the left, modules list;

on the right, `Properties>Build` Tools Version 
there maybe are more than one modules.

change `"Build Tools Version"` for every Module.

it works.