# Clean Blank Android App fails to build - 'failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc1'

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, build-tools

New to Android, Tried to build a clean 'Blank App' android project.

I get the below error, which is confusing because I have version 24 installed using the SDK manager not sure why its looking for versoin 23. It doesn't give me any kind of line number to look at though, any suggestions? Thank you.

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42220Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> aidl is missing

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.243 secs
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.136 secs
```

Comment: How does your gradle file looks like?

Comment: As you updated your build tool to `23.0.0 rc2` it unable to load `23.0.0 rc1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [AndroidStudio: Failed to sync Install build tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665001/androidstudio-failed-to-sync-install-build-tools)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Open the SDK Manager and find the version of the Android SDK Build-tools which is installed and that you want to use.
Then go to Gradle Scripts > build.gradle (Module: app). Set the buildToolsVersion to your version.

**Edit:**
There is an easier solution. Right click on the project > Open Module Settings. Choose the Complie Sdk Version and Build Tools Version you want to use.

Comment: This should checked as answer

Comment: but in android studio cannot find 23.0.0 rc2

Answer (score 4):

If you cannot find 23.0.0 rc1 in sdk mananger, you can modify gradle's sdk version.
How? edit build.gradle like this, and change buildToolsVersion.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sunjiajia.androidnewwidgetsdemo"
        minSdkVersion 14
            targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### find the BuildTools ids you want to install,

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/prayagupd/Library/Android/sdk/

$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android list sdk -a | grep "revision 23"
  10- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.3
  11- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.2
  12- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23.0.1
  13- Android SDK Build-tools, revision 23 (Obsolete)
```

Then, install the buildTool version you want, eg. `23.0.1` as `23` is obsolete.

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android update sdk -a -u -t 12
```

#### You can achieve the same thing using

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/android sdk
```

which will show the buildTools in UI as below,

[image]

Then `./gradlew clean build` should be SUCCESSFUL.