# Show error when import project from Github to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I want import project from Github to Android Studio but show me this error :
Click too see error : [Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8aMU.jpg)

How can I fix it?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya , github project Gradle : https://github.com/Yalantis/uCrop/blob/master/sample/build.gradle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first do this .

1. Open the SDK Manager
2. **Upgrade version of the Android SDK Build-tools which want to use(23)**.

You should check **['failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859449/clean-blank-android-app-fails-to-build-failed-to-find-build-tools-revision-23)**

Comment: @Dr.Snap Its our duty .Glad to help .

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your SDK and download SDK version 23 tools from SDK manager.