# android studio project opening on different machine gives error

Tags: android, android-studio

I am having android studio 1.2.1.1 on both machine 
i was working with the project on old machine but now for some reason i have to use different machine on which i have installed the same version android studio
so whenever i try to open the project on new machine it gives me error i have attached screenshot of the error

event if i create new project to check if my old project is having any issues new peoject also gives same erros.

i found something wrong with the file structure as u can also see in the second image screenshot file  where you can see that there is only one build.gradle file is present generally there are two files.one file is not showing in gradle scripts.

[image]

[image]

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665001/androidstudio-failed-to-sync-install-build-tools

Comment: On your new machine the build too with specified version i.e. 23.0.0 rc2 is not installed. You may either install it by via SDK manager or change the version number in build.gradle file with the installed version.

Comment: i have already downloaded and it is present in sdk folder @Abdullah

Comment: Could you cross check if it is rc2 or some other rcX version?

Comment: its rc3 version sorry for mistake @Abdullah

Comment: but sdk manager not showing build tool for rc2

Comment: i am able to fix it by just copying ..\sdk\build-tools\23.0.0_rc2 folder from my old machine to new machines sdk path