# Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc2 - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I been developing my project in my MacBook pro using Android Studio. I stored my project in a GitHub repo. But now I’m using Windows laptop so I cloned my project and try to run in Android Studio and I am getting the following error:

```
Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc2
Install Build Tools 23.0.0 rc2 and sync project
```

I clicked on

```
Install Build Tools 23.0.0 rc2 and sync project” but I’m getting another error:
Loading SDK information...
```

Ignoring unknown package filter 'build-tools-23.0.0-preview'Warning: The package filter removed all packages. There is nothing to install.
         Please consider trying to update again without a package filter.

Install Failed. Please check your network connection and try again. You may continue with creating your project, but it will not compile correctly without the missing components. (I have already checked my network connection, I’m connected to the internet using a wired connection).

When I clone my project in a Macbook everything works fine, so I'm not sure why it's not working in Windows.

Here is the screenshot:[image]

Comment: Try this might helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665001/androidstudio-failed-to-sync-install-build-tools change your project build tool version.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, aplogies as I forgot to mentioin I already tried that and it didn't work for me

Comment: Can you install Latest Build tools version 24 I guess from SDK manager and try If you persists with same error?

Comment: Apparently in 3.0, this issue seems to be fixed. I was connected to Internet, and Studio downloaded the required Build Tool (26 in my case) and installed it, and synced gradle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
```

Then

Clicking the button **Sync Project With Gradle Files** should do the trick:

**`Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`**

If that fails, try running **Rebuild project**:

**`Build -> Rebuild Project`**

For more details ,you can visit

[AndroidStudio: Failed to sync Install build tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30665001/androidstudio-failed-to-sync-install-build-tools)

Comment: thanks IntelliJ where can I configure these settings: compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

Comment: ignore my previous message, I found it in build.gradle file

Answer (score 5):

AS far as your this error line concern

> Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc2 Install Build
>   Tools 23.0.0 rc2 and sync project

It clearly says that you need to install the above mention package to build the project I mean to see the project according to new build version and techniques. So you need to update your sdk .

now come to the second error , There are couple of posibilites which I can think of 
1. Make sure you are not behind any type of proxy, if so then set that proxy in your AS too.

2. if you have not any real issue in your network such as As I described above, then You are better to delete the folder of 23.0.0 rc2 and respective folder I mean 23XX folders. and then try launching the sdk manager again

I hope this would solve your problem , mean while if you want to see your project on different build version , please see the image below and try this 
[image]

I hope this would solve your problem.

Edit 2: As I read your comment after posting this answer

You should change the build tool version in your build.gradle file in the Android studio. I think that this would work 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have changed compileSdkVersion and buildToolsVersion in gradle settings like below.It works.

compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

By 
Kalaimani.R