# Can't find particular version of build tools

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to compile code examples from github, but I haven't been able to, because I keep getting an error:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc2
```

My local.properties has the SDK path defined like this:

```
sdk.dir=/mnt/sda2/Android/Sdk
```

When I run the /mnt/sda2/Android/Sdk/tools/android, it states the the build tools 23.0.1, 23.0.2 and 23.0.3 are present, but I can't find 23.0.0 rc2, is that the same as 23.0.2?

[image]

I tried another example, and got an error for different build tools version:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:preBuild'.
> failed to find Build Tools revision 21.1.1
```

But the closest version the SDK manager lists is Build Tools revision 21.1.2, there's no 21.1.1 version.

Any hints please? thank you!

Comment: here it is possible duplicate of your question , check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33010279/2919483

Comment: @RajshreeTiwari thank you once again! If you'll post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it. Thanks again!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:failed to find Build Tools revision 23.0.0 rc2 - Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010106/errorfailed-to-find-build-tools-revision-23-0-0-rc2-android-studio)