# Android Studio Error: Failed to find build tools revision 24.0.0 rc4

Tags: android, android-studio, build, git-clone

I cloned a project from github, and I have the following error in the Build: `Failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0 rc4`. This is the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0 rc4'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.project02.projects"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

I have In File->Project Structere -> Build Tools Revision -> 24.0.0 rc4. And in the SDK directory the folder is 24.0.0-rc4.

I tried to change to 23.0.2, but with that I obtain this errors in the Run: **Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at

https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html** and

**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37837619/2313149 watch out this answer.

Comment: Don't use `rc4`.  Just use `buildToolsVersion = '24.0.0'`

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting is because you're overriding the previous built tool with the new one that doesn't exist in your built-tools folder.

Make sure you download the intended built tool from the SDK manager and then configure the gradle file appropiately. Check and see if that works.

Comment: In the folder ...android-sdk\build-tools\, I have the 24.0.0-rc4 and 23.0.2 folders, and in the SDK Manager both is installed

Comment: Change "24.0.0 rc4" -> "24.0.0-rc4". Add the dash to the string for buildToolsVersion in the gradle file

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.
I run "./gradlew build" on commandline and change buildToolVersion "24".
While the command is running, the SDK will be installed and everything goes OK.