# aidl is missing in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to run [Sample of Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start?configured) for Android using **Android SDK Version 6.0, API 23**
Now the sample has used API 22 but I want to run for API 23, so the changes I made in application level built.gradle file are as below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gcm.play.android.samples.com.gcmquickstart"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    // Testing dependencies
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.0'
}
```

I updated Android Studio to the latest version, but now the following error has occurred.

```
:app:compileDebugAidl FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> aidl is missing
```

For the solution I have tried [updating android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506406/aidl-is-missing-android-studio) as given in the link.

Comment: Not sure if it'd matter, but shouldn't `compileSdkVersion` be just `23`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I did to get past this issue is to first change the build tools to 23.0.1, like so:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
```

and my targetSdkVersion to 23 as well.

And update these parameters in the top level script:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.3.0-beta1'
```

Hope that helps.