# Android Studio Aidl is missing Ubuntu 15

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, gradle, android-build

I have had to move my project from Windows to Ubuntu due to a dependency [external]. I have installed android studio latest from google on Ubuntu 15 with Oracle java 8 but , my same project which was building successfully on windows does not build on Ubuntu even with all SDK tools and correct gradle version installed.

i have tried many different combinations of gradle version and android build tools version after seeing the answers on stackoverflow on another question.. But still could't fix.

Here is the gradle console log error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':compileDebugAidl'.
> aidl is missing
```

Here is my gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'


    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }

    // Do not abort build if lint finds errors
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
}
```

Comment: Use below link for Reference : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506406/aidl-is-missing-android-studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506406/aidl-is-missing-android-studio)

Comment: I have tried all the instruction from this reference and all other similar questions on stackoverflow.. @Harshad

Comment: I think its something specific to ubunut/linux

Answer (score 0):

I had the EXACT same problem. And I fix that problem.

The problem is that, you have your `build-tools` for windows. It has something called `aidl.exe`. But remember that now you are on Ubuntu, that means `.exe` is no longer support by your system.

**Solution:-**

Go to your Sdk location. Delete `build-tools` folder.

Head to Android-Studio -> Open `SDK Manager` -> Go to `SDK Tools` Tab -> Install `build-tools`.

OK Cool, Now the problem is solved.