# libmultispinner:compileReleaseAidl' : aidl is missing

Tags: android, build.gradle, aidl

I have android studio on my windows machine (version : 2.3).

API Level 23,24,25 and latest build-tools installed.

I am having problem while building project ( Specifically with libmultispinner ) :

> aidl is missing.

This is build.gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '25.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

}

I have tried to update build tools and tried with upgrading/degrading while building project.

Invalidating cache didn't work either. What can be the problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30520628/7320259 try this

Comment: @ZakiPathan : Already read that answer. 

Tried to change and I can't update to Canary version.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1" try change to this and also change targetSdkVersion to 23 after doing this rebuild cache and invalidate and then run

Comment: Well, my project requires minimum 25.0.0 and I have 25.0.0, 25.0.1 and 25.0.2  I have tried with all and nothing seems to work.

Comment: so set compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 25 and also change compile with this compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0' and then rebuild invalidate and catch and then run. Hope this helps

Comment: And can you please share your project gradle.build file code

Comment: Already shared in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138328/discussion-between-zaki-pathan-and-mahadev).

Comment: that is your module: app gradle file and i need project: yourProjectName gradle file code in which you declare classpath