# java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing in Android studio 2.3.2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have installed new android plugin version 2.3.2

my gradle version 3.3

Any body have solved this type of error, It will be grate help for me, I stuck this point from last two day......

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.2.5"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smaprojects.androidhello"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: May it can help you - [aidl is missing android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506406/aidl-is-missing-android-studio)

Comment: Thanks for your comment.