# Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android, build, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

Every time I am getting this error when running my project. I can do a Clean and then Run again, and it works. But it is not an optimal solution. Any ideas?

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
```

> java.io.IOException: Failed to rename android\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\folders\3\1f\main\classes.jar to android\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\classes.jar

Comment: This issue is coming due to pro-guard enable in the release config of the app. So the solution is either remove pro-guard or put the indicated code snippet as in the link https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelease/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This bug happens when the versions of SDK, Build Tools and Gradle Plugins doesn't match (in terms of compatibility). The solution is to verify if you are using the latest versions of them. The gradle plugins are placed in the build.gradle file of the project. Other versions are in the build.gradle file of the module. For **example**, for **SDK 23**, you must use the **Build Tools 23.0.1** and gradle **plugins version 1.3.1.**

Clean the project after changing settings. (Solved my problem, and never seen it again.)

[refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing)

Comment: I tried it with **SDK 24**, **Build Tools 24.0.0** and gradle **plugin version 2.1.2**, I'me having the same problem..

Comment: @sohayb Perhaps you have an issue in your proguard file with some of the 3rd party libraries? That happened in my case...I just added the correct rules for the external library and it was sufficient.

Comment: I am using: compileSdkVersion 27, buildToolsVersion "27.0.3", minSdkVersion 16, targetSdkVersion 25 and gradle plugin version 3.0.1 
I am facing the same problem. What should I do?

Comment: same problem @salvishahzad actually you dont need the "buildToolsVersion" so you can comment that line and android get the version that works with gradle in my case i can solve the problem adding --dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8 like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010942/getting-warnings-with-proguard-with-external-libraries/36011233#36011233

Comment: In my case Issue was : "The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.3.1"

Answer (score 4):

Remove lines from *proguard-rules.txt* that contains:

`-injars`, `-outjars`, or `-libraryjars`

and rebuild.

Comment: where can the proguard-rules.txt file be found?

Comment: @salvishahzad in my case: android/app/proguard-rules.pro

Answer (score 1):

in my case it was okhttp proguard rules after adding them it worked fine

```
#OKhttp RULES START
-dontwarn okhttp3.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
#OKhttp RULES END

#picasso rules START
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
#picasso rules END
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing `minifyEnabled true` from release config worked for me.

Comment: I think that's only a temporary solution for someone who is not wanted to do it. like disable R8, or not using proguard

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was fixed by downgrading the Proguard version used by Gradle to generate the signed apk. You can downgrade it by placing this block inside the project level build.gradle file. Place it into the buildscript block.

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'net.sf.proguard:proguard-gradle:5.2.1'
    }
}
```

You can check the current version of Proguard by executing this command at the project root folder:

```
./gradlew buildEnvironment | grep proguard
```

Here is part of the Proguard stacktrace to help others find the problem I was having.

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:283)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:173)
at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:48)
at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:225)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at proguard.optimize.info.NonEmptyStackReturnMarker.setReturnsWithNonEmptyStack(NonEmptyStackReturnMarker.java:102)
at proguard.optimize.info.NonEmptyStackReturnMarker.markReturnWithNonEmptyStack(NonEmptyStackReturnMarker.java:95)
at proguard.optimize.info.NonEmptyStackReturnMarker.visitSimpleInstruction(NonEmptyStackReturnMarker.java:76)
...
at proguard.optimize.Optimizer.execute(Optimizer.java:649)
at proguard.ProGuard.optimize(ProGuard.java:328)
at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:127)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:54)
at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:254)
... 5 more
```

Comment: Hi I also have the same problem , can you help, for the issue please follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45629710/build-fails-with-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelease-on-upgra

Answer (score 0):

You should try this: add in proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Comment: Add this line in your `proguard-rules.pro` file to fix this problem . @salvishahzad

    `-ignorewarnings`

Answer (score -5):

It's works when you modify minifyEnabled to false.

refer this [Android Studio Signed APK ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995401/android-studio-signed-apk-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelea)

Comment: minifyEnabled to false = disabled proguard