# app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

```
Error:Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
```

> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

I have tried my best to find the solution but I did not get, whereas I found many questions.

Is there anything to ignore these warnings, I just want to generate a secure signed apk, therefore I have used `minifyEnabled` **true**

Message:

```
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find superclass or interface com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceFactory
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.URLFetchService
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPMethod
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPResponse
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPRequest
Warning:retrofit.appengine.UrlFetchClient: can't find referenced class com.google.appengine.api.urlfetch.HTTPHeader
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Headers
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Headers
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Headers
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find referenced class okio.BufferedSink
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find referenced class okio.BufferedSink
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$1: can't find referenced class okio.BufferedSink
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:retrofit.client.OkClient$2: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentSequencedCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpmcArrayQueueConsumerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.MpmcArrayQueueProducerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpmcArrayQueueConsumerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpmcArrayQueueProducerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscArrayQueueConsumerField: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.SpscArrayQueueProducerFields: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.UnsafeAccess: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
```

Comment: add  `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'` in dependency

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua

Comment: @MD I posted updated log.. still getting 72 Warnings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use ProGuard you have to **always resolve all warnings** to be able to process further with the build.

These warnings tell you that the libraries reference some code and there are no sources for that. That might and might not be ok. It depends if the problematic code ever get called.

In this case the libraries reference some code but the code doesn't seem to be ever called (e.g. because you didn't add some other library). In that case add `-dontwarn` rules to `proguard-rules.pro` file.

You use Retrofit and Picasso libraries. Try adding these rules:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation interface * {
    @retrofit.http.** <methods>;
}

-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
```

It might fix your problem.

Note that you might experience further problems in runtime especially if any of those libraries use reflection and the code was shrunk and/or obfuscated. Then it's probable that you'll need more ProGuard rules for other libraries.

**Edit:** 
To resolve RxJava related warnings add this dependency:

```
// ProGuard rules for RxJava
compile 'com.artemzin.rxjava:proguard-rules:1.1.1.0'
```

It adds necessary ProGuard rules for RxJava.

Comment: getting : Warning:rx.internal.util.unsafe.ConcurrentCircularArrayQueue: can't find referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe

Comment: You need few more rules for that. I updated the answer with the solution.

Comment: Yes I have successfully generated APK but still I can get source code from apk... how do I control on it... ? I have accepted your answer and tapped as useful

Comment: The final class structure depends largely on ProGuard settings. Check your configuration. This is a fairly large topic, there can be many reasons why the code isn't obfuscated (or is poorly obfuscated). 2 main reasons: 1. there's `-dontobfuscate` rule, 2. `-keep` rules are too general. Something like `-keep com.**` is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and solved it by adding the following text to `proguard-project.txt`:

```
# for transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease
# -- Picasso --
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
# -- OkHttp --
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.internal.**
# -- Apache Commons --
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.**
-ignorewarnings
-keep class *
{
    public private *;
}
```