# Android Studio Signed APK ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

When I try to generate signed in Android Studio, I've got the following error :

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

Already make some research and find that for example :

[Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua)

I followed the advice, it didn't works. So, I tried to update my `buildToolsVersion` to `23.0.2`.

Didn't work too.

It's works only when I modify `minifyEnabled` to false, and I don't want to.

Can you give me a track please ?

Comment: You're probably being asked to build with --debug or something to get more info.  What does that reveal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try performing a clean build (Build > Clean Project) and buliding again.

If that doesn't work, it's likely Proguard is removing some important classes and/or libraries in your app. Take a look at the warnings generated above the error message in the log. You'll need to add rules to your proguard-rules.pro file to keep the necessary classes. [Here is an example of the rules required to keep the Butterknife library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/104).

Comment: Fault to JodaTime. Just had this :

`-dontwarn org.joda.time.**`

 to my proguard-rules.pro file, it's works. Thank you really really much Colin, drinks on me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, and I don't know why it happened.

I have tried lot of solutions without success.

Except adding these lines to my ProGuard file (proguard-rules.pro) :

```
-ignorewarnings

-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

Then Clean and Rebuilt, then generate release apk.

Thanks to Rahul...

Comment: Thanks - after frigging around with 'version' compatibility around gradle this was actually the fix for me.

Comment: Note that this directive will prevent proguard from removing any unused classes, which may greatly increase the size of your app. You may want to consider using a more targeted directive (for example, only keeping the package that is causing the original error).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepattributes EnclosingMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your Gradle plugin and it will work.