# How to enable proguard in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-proguard

[image]

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

I have enabled minifyEnabled, but it is not allowing me to generate signed apk. 
Error:Execution failed for task `':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'`.

> Job failed, see logs for details
>   It is throwing such error while generating signed apk. I have also mentioned

```
-ignorewarnings
-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

in `proGuard` rules.

Comment: what is error log?

Comment: take a look at this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35995401/android-studio-signed-apk-apptransformclassesandresourceswithproguardforrelea

Comment: is that your full proguard file?

Comment: This happens normally when your SDK, Build Tools and Gradle version does't match. Check are you correct versions or not.

Comment: worth looking
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua

Comment: Try to check whether proguard_rules.pro file is inside your project folder

Answer (score 0):

Change this -:

```
minifyEnabled true
```

To-:

```
minifyEnabled false
```

It will definately work.