# Android Studio:Warning when generate Signed Apk in release mode Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind

Tags: android, jackson, apk

I'm using the jackson-json dependency in an Android project, and generate Signed Apk in release mode, I get the following errors:

```
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.NioPathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.NioPathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Paths
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.NioPathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.NioPathSerializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:there were 26 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.


Error:Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.> Job failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 17.808 secs
Information:1 error
Information:16 warnings
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36011233/2070636) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28022792/2070636), you can ignore those warning in your proguard file using:

```
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
```

**Edit**:
To fix new run-time error in comments below, add:

```
 -keepattributes InnerClasses
```

Comment: Thanks @A.A. , it generate signed APK successfully but  when i run signed apk application it gives following error

`Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
android.os.AsyncTask$3.done (AsyncTask.java:300)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion (FutureTask.java:355)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException (FutureTask.java:222)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:242)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run`

Comment: in cont. also flowing error

`Caused by java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: PUBLIC_ONLY
java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotation (Class.java)
java.lang.Class.getAnnotation (Class.java:290)
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.VisibilityChecker$Std.<clinit> ()
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<clinit> ()
com.doctorstay.a.b.doInBackground ()
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call (AsyncTask.java:288)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)`

Comment: @Jignesh-Bhadani Try `-keepattributes InnerClasses`

Comment: above Error resolved but data are not coming from API, It display flowing Toast message

**no serializer found for class com.pakagename.e.t and no properties discovered to create..**

Comment: @Jignesh-Bhadani See [here](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-jsonmappingexception) for possible solution for that one

Comment: @ A.A  without signed apk i don't get this Toast msg  **no serializer found for class com.pakagename.e.t and no properties discovered to create..**

but when i signed apk then only display this Toast msg **no serializer found for class com.pakagename.e.t and no properties discovered to create..**

Comment: Please add parts of your code that may be causing that error, e.g. your `AsyncTask` code

Comment: in logcat , flowing error are logged before ***no serializer found for class com.pakagename.e.t and no properties discovered to create..** this error

`Could not find class 'java.beans.Transient', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl.<init>
ould not find class 'java.beans.ConstructorProperties', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl.findConstructorName
Could not find class 'java.beans.Transient', referenced from method com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.Java7SupportImpl.findTransient `

Comment: OK try this: `-keep class java.beans.** {*;}`

Comment: Also see this code [snippet](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets/pull/114/files)