# Android studio - Execution failed for task :app:transformclasseswithdexfordebug

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build.gradle

I am a beginner and when I try to run "Hello world" app in emulator there is always one error and it states :

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Everybody is saying that I should add: `multiDexEnabled` true, but it does not help at all. PLEASE HELP ME :) I would just like to view my app in emulator...

Thank you!!!

Comment: Can you post the file build.gradle to here. 
And have you tried with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua

Comment: It would help if you would post your gradle build file.

Comment: close android studio, go to your project folder, delete folders 'build', 'app/build' and '.gradle' (it might be hidden). Then open your Android Studio. It would regerate these folders

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and for me it was conflict of the support libaries.
Remove one of them, probably you have the same conflict.
Project and all dependencies libraries must infer to only one "android-support-v4.jar" or other, but only one.

I hope it will help.