# Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'

Tags: android

I have implemented proguard and trying to generate signed apk but i always get the error.
Error:Execution failed for task':mobile:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'
Here is my build.gradle file code.

```html
apply plugin: 'org.moallemi.advanced-build-version'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'hugo'//for method logging (only in debug builds)
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'// to check for dependency updates

advancedVersioning {
    codeOptions {
        versionCodeType org.moallemi.gradle.internal.VersionCodeType.DATE
    }
    nameOptions {
        versionMajor 0
        versionMinor 2
        versionPatch 9
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdk
    buildToolsVersion rootProject.ext.buildToolsVersion
    def buildNumber = (System.getenv("BUILD_NUMBER") ?: advancedVersioning.versionCode) as int

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "pct.droid"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdk
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdk
        versionCode buildNumber
        versionName advancedVersioning.versionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        mainConfig {
            keyAlias System.getenv("S_ALIAS").toString() ?: ""
            keyPassword System.getenv("S_KEYPASS").toString() ?: ""
            storeFile System.getenv("S_KEYSTORE").toString() ? file(System.getenv("S_KEYSTORE").toString()) : file("")
            storePassword System.getenv("S_KEYPASS").toString() ?: ""
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.mainConfig
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/beans.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            universalApk false
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
        }
    }

    project.ext.versionCodes = ["armeabi": 1, "armeabi-v7a": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86": 4, "x86_64": 4]
}

//to check for dependency updates,
//run ./gradlew dependencyUpdates -Drevision=release
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${rootProject.ext.appCompatVersion}"

    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:${rootProject.ext.butterknifeVersion}"
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    compile 'com.larswerkman:HoloColorPicker:1.5'
    compile 'com.gu:option:1.3'
    compile 'net.rdrei.android.dirchooser:library:3.0@aar'
    compile 'com.github.johnkil.android-robototextview:robototextview:2.4.3'
    
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.2.0'

    compile project(':base')
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.2.3'

    compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'

    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${rootProject.ext.daggerVersion}"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:${rootProject.ext.butterknifeVersion}"

    provided "javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:${rootProject.ext.javaxAnnotationVersion}"

}
```

Here is the code of proguard-rules.pro

```html
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}
```

Output i got :

```html
Information:Gradle tasks [:mobile:assembleRelease]
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpConnection
Warning:library class com.android.internal.http.multipart.MultipartEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:library class org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.auth.MalformedChallengeException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.auth.params.AuthParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.NonRepeatableRequestException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.RedirectException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase extends or implements program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.params.AllClientPNames extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.CoreConnectionPNames
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.params.AllClientPNames extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.CoreProtocolPNames
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.params.ClientParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestDefaultHeaders extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestTargetAuthentication extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpRequestInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpResponseInterceptor
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity extends or implements program class org.apache.http.entity.HttpEntityWrapper
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ManagedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.ManagedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpClientConnection
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.OperatedClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpInetConnection
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnConnectionParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
Warning:library class org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnRouteParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
Warning:library class org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.ProtocolException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.cookie.params.CookieSpecParamBean extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.HttpAbstractParamBean
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.ClientParamsStack extends or implements program class org.apache.http.params.AbstractHttpParams
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.EntityEnclosingRequestWrapper extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpEntityEnclosingRequest
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.RequestWrapper extends or implements program class org.apache.http.message.AbstractHttpMessage
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.client.TunnelRefusedException extends or implements program class org.apache.http.HttpException
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection extends or implements program class org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultResponseParser extends or implements program class org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionInputBuffer extends or implements program class org.apache.http.io.SessionInputBuffer
Warning:library class org.apache.http.impl.conn.LoggingSessionOutputBuffer extends or implements program class org.apache.http.io.SessionOutputBuffer
Warning:com.amazon.whisperlink.port.android.KeyStoreGenerator: can't find referenced class com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider
Warning:com.amazon.whisperlink.port.android.KeyStoreGenerator: can't find referenced class com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name
Warning:com.amazon.whisperlink.port.android.KeyStoreGenerator: can't find referenced class com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator
Warning:com.amazon.whisperlink.port.android.KeyStoreGenerator: can't find referenced class com.android.org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.X509Name
Warning:com.amazon.whisperlink.port.android.KeyStoreGenerator: can't find referenced class com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator
Warning:com.amazon.whisperlink.service.fling.media.SimplePlayerException: can't find referenced method 'int compareTo(org.apache.thrift.TEnum,org.apache.thrift.TEnum)' in program class org.apache.thrift.TBaseHelper
Warning:com.amazon.whisperlink.service.fling.media.SimplePlayerStatus: can't find referenced method 'int compareTo(org.apache.thrift.TEnum,org.apache.thrift.TEnum)' in program class org.apache.thrift.TBaseHelper
Warning:com.amazon.whisperplay.fling.media.receiver.impl.MetricsClient: can't find referenced class com.amazon.client.metrics.AndroidMetricsFactoryImpl
Warning:com.amazon.whisperplay.fling.media.receiver.impl.MetricsClient: can't find referenced class com.amazon.client.metrics.MetricsFactory
Warning:com.amazon.whisperplay.fling.media.receiver.impl.MetricsClient: can't find referenced class com.amazon.client.metrics.MetricEvent
Warning:com.amazon.whisperplay.fling.media.receiver.impl.MetricsClient: can't find referenced class com.amazon.client.metrics.MetricsFactory
Warning:com.amazon.whisperplay.fling.media.receiver.impl.MetricsClient: can't find referenced class com.amazon.client.metrics.AndroidMetricsFactoryImpl
Warning:com.amazon.whisperplay.fling.media.receiver.impl.MetricsClient: can't find referenced class com.amazon.client.metrics.MetricsFactory
Warning:com.amazon.whisperplay.fling.media.receiver.impl.MetricsClient: can't find referenced class com.amazon.client.metrics.MetricEvent
Warning:com.amazon.whisperplay.fling.media.receiver.impl.MetricsClient: can't find referenced class com.amazon.client.metrics.MetricsFactory
Warning:com.amazon.whisperplay.fling.media.receiver.impl.MetricsClient: can't find referenced class com.amazon.client.metrics.MetricEvent
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.DOMSerializer: can't find referenced class org.w3c.dom.bootstrap.DOMImplementationRegistry
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.PathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.PathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Paths
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ext.PathDeserializer: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.Transient
Warning:com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector$Java7Support: can't find referenced class java.beans.ConstructorProperties
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.CacheControl
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:com.squareup.picasso.OkHttpDownloader: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Cache
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.MediaType
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request$Builder
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.OkHttpClient
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Call
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.ResponseBody
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Response
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.XmlRpcClient$MethodCall: can't find referenced class com.squareup.okhttp.Request
Warning:de.timroes.axmlrpc.serializer.DateTimeSerializer: can't find referenced class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
Warning:okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
Warning:okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.entity.AbstractHttpEntity
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.params.HttpParams
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpHost
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpRequest
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.HttpClient depends on program class org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpEntity
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions depends on program class org.apache.http.HttpResponse
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase depends on program class org.apache.http.ProtocolVersion
Warning:library class org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpRequestBase depends on program class org.apache.http.RequestLine
Warning:there were 140 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 80 instances of library classes depending on program classes.
Warning:there were 2 unresolved references to program class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 52.137 secs
Information:1 error
Information:175 warnings
```

Comment: have you checked this [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33953133/5993410)

Comment: yes but i think i had to use some rules for the warnings as i edit above