# Android minifyEnabled gives error for retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying to generate a signed APK with minifyEnabled set to true in Gradle:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

and added these to my proguard file:

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
```

but I get these errors:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced method 'boolean isDefault()' in library class java.lang.reflect.Method
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles$Lookup
Warning:retrofit2.Platform$Java8: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
Warning:there were 8 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
Warning:there were 1 unresolved references to library class members.
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

and can't build the apk file. We can't have minifyEnabled as true and use retrofit library? how can this be fixed?

Comment: [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua)

Answer (score 1):

You can have `minifyEnabled` as true and use any number of libraries. Just one thing to make note of its to add the proguard rules of every library in the proguard-rules.pro file. Check retrofits proguard handling [here](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Lastly adding a proguard-rules.pro for your reference this is for the project im handling. (You might also need to notify proguard to exclude your POJO classes. Check example)

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /Users/yogeshmalpani/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class com.pushwoosh.** { *; }
-keep class com.arellomobile.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.pushwoosh.**
-dontwarn com.arellomobile.**
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewInjector { *; }
-keepnames class * { @butterknife.InjectView *;}
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
 -dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**
 -keep class org.codehaus.** { *; }
 -keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
 public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *; }
# My POJO class directory
-keep public class com.app_name.model.pojo.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
  public protected private *;
}
# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using retrofit 2,

```
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
```