# Error for Proguard Rules while Generating Signed APK

Tags: java, android, memory-management

This is my `build.gradle`(app) file..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.odev09.eazyvisi"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 19
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
```

When I Generate Signed APK it will give below error

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines to your `proguard-rules.pro`

```
-ignorewarnings

-keep class * {
    public private *;
}
```

Comment: @Nikunj your rule will disable proguard, am i right? it seems to be a soldier without wepon!

Answer (score 0):

Just try,

Your `compileSdkVersion 26` so You need to change Targetsdk version

```
targetSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
```

my suggestion try this, 
applicationId contain three parts so change this one also

```
(eg: com.test.android)
```