# BUILD FAILED Android Studio Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, build

**My problem is:** Not let me compile, I have updated the recommendations that gives me Android Studio, but still the problems continue.

```
Warning:Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: proguard.ParseException: Expecting class member name before ';' in line 16 of file 'D:\Aplicaciones\You Fly\app\proguard-rules.pro'

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
```

> Job failed, see logs for details

Comment: there is a Try these answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua)

Comment: would you include you're `proguard-ruler.pro` file