# proguard - Duplicate zip entry classes.jar

Tags: android, proguard, in-app-billing, android-proguard

I am unable to build signed apk. I implemented this library into my project: https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

after I implemented it, when I try to generate apk this error appears:

```
    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\MealPlanner\app\build\intermediates\transforms\proguard\release\jars\3\1f\main.jar] (Can't read [C:\Users\Admin\StudioProjects\MealPlanner\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.billingclient\billing\1.0\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**/*.class)] (Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:com/android/vending/billing/IInAppBillingService$Stub$Proxy.class]))
```

I don't have any aidl file in my project and I tried outjars and exluding it from build.gradle but still the problem persists.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i was trying to build an in-app billing app for Google play (based on their TrivialDrive sample) in `Android Studio 3.2.1`, `buildtools version 28.0.3`, i also found that generation of the signed release APK was blocked by `Java.IO.Exception, transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease, duplicate zip entry classes etcetera` ...

First i followed recommendations on the internet to adapt the proguard pro file, then i updated the buildtools version, changed my gradle file many times, nothing helped!

The strange thing is that there was no problem with the original trivialdrive sample build 2 weeks ago with dependencies including 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'.

After deleting implementation `'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.1'`, the build was successful!
So i think something was changed for in-app billing dependency requirements??

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue recently after I added third party library (open source) and spend really many hours struggling to get through. Stack overflow has many questions and discussion around it. Everyone has suggested different solution However I followed [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33953133/1911652) which suggested to correct version numbers. But that alone did not solve my problem.

Since my case was same like yours (that is `"Duplicate zip entry"` and `"java.io.IOException: Can't write"`) I thought to answer your question.

Here is what I did (other than version changes as mentioned above):

In the build.gradle of library that you've added, add this:

```
buildTypes
{
    release
    {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'billing-proguard-rules.pro'
    }

    debug
    {
        minifyEnabled false
        shrinkResources false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'billing-proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

And your billing-proguard-rules.pro should look something like this:

```
-keep public class * extends com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.** { *; }
-keepclassmembernames class * extends com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.** { *; }
```

Since billing library you imported is open source (like same is my case) it is fine to keep it as it is.

You are ready to go!