# Cannot Build release apk version

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard, android-proguard

The Problem occur when i generate release version of the APK . I have already view this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35890257/android-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexforrelease) and try all things mention but problem still exists Please point me in the right direction

**Error**

> Error:Execution failed for
>   task:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout$1.class

**gradle**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        }
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.wildstone.cv_maker"
            minSdkVersion 19

            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            targetSdkVersion 27

            multiDexEnabled true //important
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
        compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua)

Comment: may be you miss some proguard rules

Comment: Which build tool version are you using?

Comment: buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generally happens when you are using different versions of SDK and support libraries.
Replace the versions of these

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

and it should work.

Comment: try to invalidate caches and restart after replacing to 27.

Comment: @SaadZahoor High Five now appreciate the solution by voting up ;)