# is it a must to enable minify when generate signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio

i tried to generate signed apk but i always got this error when i enable minify in the gradle..

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:196)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:221)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:217)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:212)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor302.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
    at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:473)
    at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:233)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:98)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:61)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:253)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:173)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)
    ... 1 more
```

and this is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.xxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 4
        versionName "4.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
}
```

some reference tells that it could be problem with external library that i use, i tried to find which library but still won't solve this issue.. 
i upgraded my AS to 3.1 but still won't solve..
i updated my sdk but this still the same error appear..
but when i disable minify in gradle file i didn't get this error

am i missing something here?

adding java compiler error message

```
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$1: can't find superclass or interface org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher    
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$2: can't find superclass or interface org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher    
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$3: can't find superclass or interface org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher    
org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: can't find superclass or interface org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing  
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find superclass or interface org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher  
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find superclass or interface org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher  
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find superclass or interface org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher    
org.junit.internal.matchers.TypeSafeMatcher: can't find superclass or interface org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher    
library class android.test.AndroidTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase 
library class android.test.AndroidTestRunner extends or implements program class junit.runner.BaseTestRunner    
library class android.test.InstrumentationTestCase extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase 
library class android.test.InstrumentationTestSuite extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestSuite   
library class android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder$FailedToCreateTests extends or implements program class junit.framework.TestCase   
org.junit.Assert: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert    
org.junit.Assert: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher  
org.junit.Assume: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers 
org.junit.Assume: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher  
org.junit.Assume: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers 
org.junit.Assume: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher  
org.junit.AssumptionViolatedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$1: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$1: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$1: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$1: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$1: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$2: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$2: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$2: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$2: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$2: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$2: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$2: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$3: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$3: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$3: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$3: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.experimental.results.ResultMatchers$3: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher   
org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.StringDescription  
org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description    
org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing 
org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.StringDescription  
org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description    
org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher    
org.junit.internal.AssumptionViolatedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description    
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Factory 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Factory 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description 
org.junit.internal.matchers.StacktracePrintingMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Factory 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableCauseMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher 
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Factory   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Description   
org.junit.internal.matchers.ThrowableMessageMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher   
org.junit.internal.matchers.TypeSafeMatcher: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.BaseMatcher   
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory 
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean  
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory 
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.FailOnTimeout: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean  
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers 
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher$CombinableBothMatcher 
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher$CombinableEitherMatcher   
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers 
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher   
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher  
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher$CombinableBothMatcher 
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher  
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher$CombinableBothMatcher 
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher  
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher$CombinableEitherMatcher   
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher  
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.core.CombinableMatcher$CombinableEitherMatcher   
org.junit.matchers.JUnitMatchers: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher  
org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory  
org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean  
org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.ManagementFactory  
org.junit.rules.DisableOnDebug: can't find referenced class java.lang.management.RuntimeMXBean  
org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher    
org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector$1: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher  
org.junit.rules.ExpectedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers    
org.junit.rules.ExpectedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.StringDescription   
org.junit.rules.ExpectedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers    
org.junit.rules.ExpectedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.StringDescription   
org.junit.rules.ExpectedException: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher 
org.junit.rules.ExpectedExceptionMatcherBuilder: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher   
org.junit.rules.ExpectedExceptionMatcherBuilder: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers  
org.junit.rules.ExpectedExceptionMatcherBuilder: can't find referenced class org.hamcrest.Matcher   
there were 308 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.  
there were 5 instances of library classes depending on program classes. 
Exception while processing task java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
```

Comment: does this error only occur when you minify the apk otherwise not?

Comment: yes.. only when i minify apk..

Comment: is it ok not to minify apk

Comment: For release apk you should strictly minify..

Comment: still return the same issue.. i added error message from java compiler..

Comment: Did you check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua

Comment: i tried but still same issue appear.. i updated gradle version, gradle plugin version and sdk tools to the latest version.. but still the same error message appear..

Comment: I add `-ignore warnings` to proguard rule.. and apk generated.. but is this solution ok to be done?