# Flutter app Android studio 3.2.1, build fail

Tags: build, flutter, apk, proguard

I updated Android studio to 3.2.1 and run 'flutter build apk' in terminal of Mac, it shows below error. I was able to build apk successfully before updated Android studio.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
> Job failed, see logs for details
```

here with my proguard-rules.pro

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33877134/10269042

Answer (score 1):

This fixed my issue,

```
 #Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.**  { *; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.**  { *; }
-dontwarn android.**
```

Check explanation here: 
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40218#issuecomment-531047713

Answer (score 0):

Goto android/app/build.gradle and try `minifyEnabled false` it should work