# Unable to open android project in windows

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to android and developing android application of password manager. I started working in Ubuntu android studio and due to some problem I switched to windows 10 but Unable to import project showing error of app:compileDebugAidl or Aidl is missing. I tried to change version from 23.2.0 to 21.0.2 or 21.0.0 but unable to solve. please suggest

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.devil.password"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

Comment: see this question which references the same error you are having, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing

Comment: Yes. I'm using same SDK folder for both also installed Repository,\.

Comment: I have seen that post and if you read my problem I have also tried to change version still i wasn't able to solve. Though i posted here.

Comment: Your issue shouldn't be coming from gradle I wouldn't think, unless maybe your computer running Windows doesn't have an up to date SDK to match the one declared, but I think that would toss an error in your IDE.

Comment: Thank you @zgc7009 but my sdk is Up to date. when i tried to search answer for this problem, i got only change in version to 21.0.0 or 21.0.2 or something else.