# Gradle gets error when try to paste aidl in package

Tags: android, android-studio

I try to use inapp order aidl (IInAppBillingService.aidl).when i copy this in (com.android.vending.billing) package it gets error :

[image: error image]

i found some article thats [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing) .

but i dont have Buildtools version 22.1.2 in my OpenMuduleSetting like above article.

[image: My openmodulesetting image]

how can i solve this problem ?

Comment: Please provide the full Gradle output in the question as text, not an image. The post that you linked to is not the answer to your question because `aidl.exe` was found, but is returning an error

Answer (score 0):

According to this SO issue:

> This bug happens when the versions of SDK, Build Tools and Gradle
>   Plugins doesn't match (in terms of compatibility). The solutions is
>   verify if you is using the latest versions of them. The gradle plugins
>   are placed in the build.gradle of the project, and the other versions
>   are on the build.gradle of the module. For example, for SDK 23, you
>   must use the Build Tools 23.0.1 and gradle plugins version 1.3.1.

You're using already newer `23.0.3` build tools so please check if your Gradle plugin is at least in '1.3.0' version

Try to use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.1'`