# java.lang.IllegalStateException:aidl is missing

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I imported my project from android studio version 2.1.2 to 2.2. It was working perfectly in my old android version but throws error in android studio 2.2.Solutions for this error has been posted alot after working out for a day none of the solution worked for me.What wrong i am doing here.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing
```

My project level build.gradle file is
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}


allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
}
 task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my module level build.gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.ujjwalmainali.univhub"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 6
    versionName "1.0"
}


compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"


buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/smilefam/SendBird-SDK Android/master/" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //iconify dependencies

    //iconify
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.2.2'
    // (v4.5)
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile 'com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-android-sdk:3.0.7'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.+'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.5.3'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:library:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.ogaclejapan.smarttablayout:utils-v4:1.6.1@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.0'
compile 'com.applozic.communication.uiwidget:mobicomkitui:4.63'
//app crash report
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
ext.googlePlayServicesVersion = '9.0.2'
ext.supportLibraryVersion = '23.1.1'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}
```

Comment: change the build.gradle with  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

Comment: Try reinstalling gradle plugin again

Comment: lower the buildToolsVersion below 24 , which u have in your sdk

Comment: yeah i went to that page but the purpose solution didn't work for me.so  i posted here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Still throws the same error changing my gradle to version 2.2.2

Answer (score 1):

Changing your from buildToolsVersion "24.0.0" to buildToolsVersion "23.0.3" because your compileSdkVersion is 23 as suggested by @Ironman.

Also in your project level gradle file changing 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2' to 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'

I worked it out this way.

Hope it helps.!

Comment: I changed everything suggested by @ironman but still throws the same error.

Comment: If you didn't find any solution for it yet then refer this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing