# Error while creating signed apk from android studio

Tags: android, android-proguard, android-studio-2.1

While generating signed apk, having 504 errors with following output.
Kindly let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance...

```
Error:Execution failed for task
':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
Job failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 1 mins 7.38 secs
Information:1 error
Information:1,097 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

Proguard is -

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *;}
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp3.OkHttpGlideModule
```

Added dependencies are -

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:2.6.12'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.18.0'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.0'
compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0'
provided 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations:4.0.0'
compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:4.0.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug happens when the versions of SDK, Build Tools and Gradle Plugins doesn't match (in terms of compatibility). The solutions is to verify if you are using the latest versions of them. The gradle plugins are placed in the build.gradle file of the project. Other versions are in the build.gradle file of the module. For example, for SDK 25, you must use the Build Tools 25.0.2 and gradle plugins version 2.2.3.

Clean the project after changing settings.

[refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing)

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. But when I do 'minifyEnabled false', it builds successfully. might be minification error.

Comment: you can use proguard-android.txt file