# getting errors in musicplayer App how to fix it?

Tags: java, android

I created the music player.when i build the Apk  I'm getting the error and how to fix this error please help me out of this.

getting error like this

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing 'D:\android\sdk\build-tools\25.0.3\aidl.exe' with arguments {-pD:\android\sdk\platforms\android-23\framework.aidl -oD:\app\build\generated\source\aidl\debug -ID:\app\src\main\aidl -ID:\app\src\debug\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\cardview-v7\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\palette-v7\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\percent\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\net.steamcrafted\materialiconlib\1.0.3\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\de.Maxr1998\track-selector-lib\1.1\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.github.naman14\app-theme-engine\0.5.2\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\design\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\transition\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.afollestad.material-dialogs\commons\0.9.0.2\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.afollestad.material-dialogs\core\0.9.0.2\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\recyclerview-v7\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar\library\1.1.7\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-v4\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-fragment\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-media-compat\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-core-ui\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-core-utils\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-vector-drawable\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\support-compat\25.1.0\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.crashlytics.sdk.android\crashlytics\2.6.5\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.crashlytics.sdk.android\beta\1.2.2\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.crashlytics.sdk.android\crashlytics-core\2.3.14\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.crashlytics.sdk.android\answers\1.3.10\aidl -ID:\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\io.fabric.sdk.android\fabric\1.3.14\aidl -dC:\Users\u7jyyjyj\AppData\Local\Temp\aidl5838888926807410516.d D:\app\src\main\aidl\com\droidapps\musicplayer\ITimberService.aidl}

```
my build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.droidapps.musicplayer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 19
        versionName "0.5b"
        //renderscript support mode is not supported for 21+ with gradle version 2.0
        renderscriptTargetApi 20
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            manifestPlaceholders = [ appNameSuffix:""]

        }
        debug {
            ext.enableCrashlytics = false
            versionNameSuffix "-debug"
            minifyEnabled false
            applicationIdSuffix '.dev'
            manifestPlaceholders = [ appNameSuffix:" Dev"]

            resValue "string", "fabric_api_key", "12345"
            resValue "string", "play_billing_license_key", "12345"

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        disable 'ExtraTranslation'
    }

}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
    compile 'net.steamcrafted:materialiconlib:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'de.Maxr1998:track-selector-lib:1.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.9.0.2'
    compile('com.github.naman14:app-theme-engine:0.5.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+'
}
```

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing

Comment: paste your gradle file here

Comment: added the gradle file  - Nilesh

Comment: For starters, you need to use compileSdk 25 or downgrade your supports libraries, though that may not fix that error

Comment: I'm using compileSdk 25 Also I'm getting the same error - cricket_007