# Android studio error :“Unable to locate adb”

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

I have problem with Android Studio 2.3.3. Project can not be created,I try almost everything,reinstall application etc. This problem appeared since my Windows is updated, I do not know why.

This is image of problem and message from Android studio:

[image: This is image of problem and message from Android studio]

There is also another problem because I have SDK version 26.0.2 and Android Studio is telling me that I missed some SDK tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your SDK isn't part of your PATH environmental directory then make sure your project structure is pointing to a valid SDK location:

[image]

Comment: I've tried but nothing happens,I do not know what is problem,non of advices are not working

Comment: In that case try using File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart. At that point if it is not fixed I would uninstall the SDK and Android Studio and reinstall the package together. Maybe something went wrong with your windows upgrade (I had no problems)

Comment: Thank you for advices but same thing,I tried to reinstall it few times

Comment: And you're sure the SDK is installed? Open a cmd prompt and go to C:/Users/<you>/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/platform-tools and then type adb. You should see the usage instructions printed, if not it will help you identify what is wrong

Comment: II don't know how but I fix.It was problem with some plugins for emulator

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30520587/5212133)

This bug happens when the versions of SDK, Build Tools and Gradle Plugins doesn't match (in terms of compatibility). The solutions is verify if you is using the latest versions of them. The gradle plugins are placed in the build.gradle of the project, and the other versions are on the build.gradle of the module. For example, for SDK 23, you must use the Build Tools 23.0.1 and gradle plugins version 1.3.1.

Comment: I sow that before I ask the question and I check again now but it doesn't working probably because I have download it yesterday from official site,so it should be good