# I'm installing Android Studio on Linux

Tags: java, android, linux

I'm installing Android Studio on Linux. And I completely updated sdk. But I encountered this problem, please help me

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing from '/home/alibaba/Android/sdk2/Sdk/build-tools/26.0.2/aidl'

Comment: A quick search on `app:compileDebugAidl` leads to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing

Answer (score 0):

This bug happens when the versions of SDK, Build Tools and Gradle Plugins doesn't match (in terms of compatibility). The solutions is verify if you is using the latest versions of them. The gradle plugins are placed in the build.gradle of the project, and the other versions are on the build.gradle of the module.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your target SDK version and build version aren't mismatched. For example, if you're compiling for API 26, then build tools version should be higher than API 26 (26.x.x and above).