# Building an apk file

Tags: android, android-proguard

I just done with coding in my application , it runs ok without any problem but I stuck in building the apk 
I want to make my apk file , gradle make some errors and I don't know how can I fix this

this is the error:

```
   org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:256)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:249)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:238)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:663)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:597)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:59)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:210)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:115)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:152)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Job failed, see logs for details
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.transform(ProGuardTransform.java:194)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:239)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:235)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:230)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    ... 108 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzjn] (with 1 known super classes) and [android/os/RemoteException] (with 5 known super classes)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:255)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.access$000(ProGuardTransform.java:63)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform$1.run(ProGuardTransform.java:171)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.Job.runTask(Job.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.SimpleWorkQueue$EmptyThreadContext.runTask(SimpleWorkQueue.java:41)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:282)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzjn] (with 1 known super classes) and [android/os/RemoteException] (with 5 known super classes)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue.findCommonClass(TypedReferenceValue.java:527)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue.generalize(TypedReferenceValue.java:320)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.TypedReferenceValue.generalize(TypedReferenceValue.java:225)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.TracedReferenceValue.generalize(TracedReferenceValue.java:276)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.TracedReferenceValue.generalize(TracedReferenceValue.java:163)
    at proguard.evaluation.value.ReferenceValue.generalize(ReferenceValue.java:354)
    at proguard.evaluation.Variables.generalize(Variables.java:136)
    at proguard.evaluation.TracedVariables.generalize(TracedVariables.java:118)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateSingleInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:804)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlock(PartialEvaluator.java:708)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitExceptionInfo(PartialEvaluator.java:1189)
    at proguard.classfile.visitor.ExceptionHandlerFilter.visitExceptionInfo(ExceptionHandlerFilter.java:67)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.exceptionsAccept(CodeAttribute.java:226)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:1135)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.evaluateInstructionBlockAndExceptionHandlers(PartialEvaluator.java:688)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute0(PartialEvaluator.java:317)
    at proguard.optimize.evaluation.PartialEvaluator.visitCodeAttribute(PartialEvaluator.java:230)
    at proguard.preverify.CodePreverifier.visitCodeAttribute0(CodePreverifier.java:115)
    at proguard.preverify.CodePreverifier.visitCodeAttribute(CodePreverifier.java:89)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.CodeAttribute.accept(CodeAttribute.java:141)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.attributesAccept(ProgramMethod.java:101)
    at proguard.classfile.attribute.visitor.AllAttributeVisitor.visitProgramMember(AllAttributeVisitor.java:95)
    at proguard.classfile.util.SimplifiedVisitor.visitProgramMethod(SimplifiedVisitor.java:93)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramMethod.accept(ProgramMethod.java:93)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.methodsAccept(ProgramClass.java:588)
    at proguard.classfile.visitor.AllMethodVisitor.visitProgramClass(AllMethodVisitor.java:47)
    at proguard.classfile.visitor.ClassVersionFilter.visitProgramClass(ClassVersionFilter.java:76)
    at proguard.classfile.ProgramClass.accept(ProgramClass.java:430)
    at proguard.classfile.ClassPool.classesAccept(ClassPool.java:124)
    at proguard.preverify.Preverifier.execute(Preverifier.java:60)
    at proguard.ProGuard.preverify(ProGuard.java:491)
    at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:197)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:64)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:249)
    ... 6 more
```

this is my proguard rules :

```
    -keep class org.apache.http.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.codec.** { *; }
-keep class org.apache.commons.logging.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.compatibility.** { *; }
-keep class android.net.http.** { *; }
-keep class javax.annotation.**{*;}
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**
-dontwarn org.apache**

-keep public class android.net.http.SslError
-keep public class android.webkit.WebViewClient
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebView
-dontwarn android.net.http.SslError
-dontwarn android.webkit.WebViewClient

-keep class cn.trinea.android.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class cn.trinea.android.** { *; }
-dontwarn cn.trinea.android.**

-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**

-keep class com.parse.**{*;}
-dontwarn com.parse.**
-keep class org.slf4j.**{*;}
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
                                public static boolean isLoggable(java.lang.String, int);
                                public static int v(...);
                                public static int i(...);
                                public static int w(...);
                                public static int d(...);
                                public static int e(...);
                            }

-keep class cn.trinea.android.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class cn.trinea.android.** { *; }
-dontwarn cn.trinea.android.**
-dontwarn org.slf4j.**


-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.* { *; }
-keep class com.google.* {  *; }
-dontwarn com.google.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzol.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.zzol.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.zzoj.**

-keep class android.os.*
-dontwarn android.os.*

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.internal.zziv
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.zziv
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}
# Keep the names of classes/members we need for client functionality.
-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
    @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
-keep class com.android.**
-keep class com.google.android.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.location.**
-keep class com.google.api.client.**
-keep class com.google.maps.android.**

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.zzjn.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.zzjn.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep class android.os.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.os.**


## Google Play Services 4.3.23 specific rules ##
## https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Proguard ##
```

this is my gradle file :

```
    dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation ('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.alirezaafkar:sundatepicker:2.0.8'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.alirezaafkar:sundatepicker:2.0.8'
    implementation 'me.cheshmak:analytics:2.0.+'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.2'
}
```

can anyone help me to solve this ? I stuck here in 2 days and I don't know what to so

thanks in advance

Comment: But why 26 alpha version of support libraries and etc? Have you tried updating them?

Comment: @Mohsen yes i've tried nothing changed

Comment: Maybe you can also use the new code shrinker R8. Just add `android.enableR8 = true` to your gradle.properties. As described here: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#new_features R8 will replace ProGuard.

Answer (score 1):

It happens when the versions of SDK, Build Tools and Gradle Plugins doesn't match. The solution is to verify if you are using the latest versions of them. The gradle plugins are placed in the build.gradle file of the project. Other versions are in the build.gradle file of the module. For example, for SDK 23, you must use the Build Tools 23.0.1 and gradle plugins version 1.3.1.

Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33877134/errorexecution-failed-for-task-androidtransformclassesandresourceswithprogua) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29766830/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugaidl-aidl-is-missing) questions.