# android - build apk file Can't find common super class of zzoj

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I want to build the apk file , the project works fine and there is no error but in building the apk , I get this error :

```
Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzoj] (with 2 known super classes) and [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzol] (with 2 known super classes)
```

this is my gradle :

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2       // increment with every release
        versionName '1.1.1'   // change with every release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    implementation ('cn.trinea.android.view.autoscrollviewpager:android-auto-scroll-view-pager:1.1.2') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.alirezaafkar:sundatepicker:2.0.8'
    implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.alirezaafkar:sundatepicker:2.0.8'
    implementation 'me.cheshmak:analytics:2.0.+'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is my akk gradle :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

I've tried lots of ways like : 
- cleaning the project
-invalidate and restart the project
-rebuild 
-remove .gradle and .ideal folder and rebuild

I also change the gradle version, different sdk version , nothing work

It's been 2 days I'm working on it

could you help me ? how can I solve this ? I'm really tired

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Building an apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52755538/building-an-apk-file)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411710/proguard-cant-find-common-super-class-java-lang-verifyerror

Comment: @Kishita not working ...